# Intercepting the Glass camera button in a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: google-glass

In the past we used to be able to register a BroadcastReceiver and receive a callback when the physical camera button was pressed. As an example I've used the open source project https://github.com/neonglass/CamButtonDisable to try it out. But it doesn't seem to be possible anymore, no callbacks are received.

The current focused activity (i.e. immersion view) does receive KEYCODE_CAMERA when the camera button is pressed, but I'd like to receive the event in a broadcastreceiver even when my activity isn't running. Is that possible?

Comment: What's your problem here? You can define a BroadcastReceiver for this purpose like this: https://github.com/neonglass/CamButtonDisable/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml#L26

Comment: As I wrote in the question, the BroadcastReceiver doesn't get any intents when the camera button is pressed. I haven't tested in 2 months though and would be interested in hearing if someone has got it working now.